# Receiving different measured values from crossK and lohboot

Tags: r-sf, spatstat

I have a marked `ppp` dataset looking at crimes and their relation to locations.

I am performing an inhomogeneous cross-K using the `Kcross.inhom`, and am using `lohboot` to bootstrap confidence intervals around the inhomogenous cross-K. However, I am getting different measured values of the `iso` for the two when we would anticipate identical values.

The crime dataset is 26k rows, unsure of how to subset to create a reproducible example.

```
#creating the ppp
crime.coords = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(crime))  #coordinates of crimes
center.coords = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(center)) #coordinates of locations 
temp = rbind(data.frame(x=crime.coords$X,y=crime.coords$Y,type='crime'),
             data.frame(x=center.coords$X,y=center.coords$Y,type='center')) #df for maked ppp
temp = ppp(temp[,1],temp[,2], window=owin(border.coords), marks=relevel(as.factor(temp$type), 'crime')) #creating marked ppp


#creating an intensity model of the crimes
temp = rescale(temp, 10000) #rescaling for polynomial model coefficients
crime.ppp = unmark(split(temp)$crime)
model.crime = ppm(crime.ppp ~ polynom(x, y, 2), Poisson())

ck = Kcross.inhom(temp, i = 'crime', j = 'center', lambdaI = model.crime) #cross K w/ intensity function
ckenv = lohboot(temp, fun='Kcross.inhom', i = 'crime', j='center', lambdaI = model.crime) #bootstrapped CIs for cross K w/ intensity function
```

Here are the values plotted, showing different curves:
[image: Plot of Kcross.inhom]

[image: Plot of lohboot results]

[image: ggplot of measured results]

A few things I've noted are that the `r` are different for both functions, and setting the `lohboot` `r` does not in fact make them identical. Unsure of where to go from here, exhausted all my resources in finding a solution.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These curves are not guaranteed to be equal. `lohboot` subdivides the data, randomly resamples the subdivisions, computes the contributions from these randomly selected subdivisions, and averages them. If you repeat the experiment you should get a slightly different answer from `lohboot` each time. See the help file for `lohboot`.

It would desirable that the two curves are close. Unfortunately the default behaviour of `lohboot` does not often achieve that. For consistency, the default behaviour follows the original implementation which was not very good. Try setting `block = TRUE` for better performance. Also try the other options `basicboot` and `Vcorrection`.

Comment: From the master himself! Thank you very much for the insight.